# Simple program Segmentation Faults with 0 command line parameters

Tags: c, parameters, fault

so I have the following program which outputs the parameter with the maximum length. I want to make an exception so when I give it 0 parameters I get an error telling me that I need at lest one parameter.

```
// Program which given an number of program parameters
// (command-line parameters, calulates the length of each one
// and writes the longest to standard output.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int i;
    int maxLength = strlen(argv[1]);    
    char* maxString = argv[1]; 

   if (argc<=0)
    {
    printf("You cannot have 0 parameters\n");
    exit(0);
    }

    for(i = 2; i < argc; ++i) 
    {
    // find out the length of the current argument
        int length = strlen(argv[i]);

        if (maxLength < length)
        {
            maxLength = length;
        maxString = argv[i];    
        } // if

    } // for

printf("Largest string is %s\n", maxString);

} // main
```

This is my code but for some reason I am getting a segmentation error when I'm giving it 0 arguments, instead of the message.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This needs a bit more of context code.

Comment: I've added the entire code.

Comment: How about you give us the line number of the segfault? Why waste our time reading code if you don't even give us that much information? Sorry, but if you don't post a backtrace along with the crash that shows a basic lack of attempt to fix it yourself.

Comment: Something that wasn't clear from your initial post, but after the edit, I wonder: can a program be called with *zero* arguments? "There is almost always at least one argument passed to a program; the name of the program itself is the first argument, argv[0]." (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Statements/Functions#main)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** after editing the question: Also you're using `argv[1]` ***before*** you checked `argc`. This is an error.

If you pass no arguments, `argc` is going to be `1` (because `argv[0]` is usually the executable name).

So

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc<=1)
    {
        printf("You cannot have 0 parameters\n");
        exit(255);
    } else
    {
        int i;
        int maxLength = 0;
        const char* maxString = 0;

        for(i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            // find out the length of the current argument
            int length = strlen(argv[i]);
            if(maxLength <= length)
            {
                maxLength = length;
                maxString = argv[i];
            }
        }
        printf("Largest string is %s\n", maxString);
    }
} // main
```

Comment: I'm still getting the segmentation fault for some reason. By the way, I added the entire code.

Answer (score 3):

If you give zero arguments in command line `argc` will be 1 not 0. The executable's name will be the first argument.